# Python: urllib.request.urlretrieve saves an empty file. Writes in it "Supplied id parameter is empty."

Tags: python, url, download, urllib

This is the type of file I want to download and save:

http://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/efetch.fcgi?db=nuccore&id=562868704,585641505&rettype=fasta&retmode=text

...and this is the test code:

```
import urllib.request
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
mystring = ' '
link = urllib.request.urlopen('http://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/elink.fcgi?dbfrom=protein&db=nuccore&linkname=protein_nuccore_mrna&id=13591999,149050462')
tree = ET.parse(link)
root = tree.getroot()
for branch in root.iter('Link'):
    for something in branch.iter('Id'):
        mystring += something.text + ','
mRNA = urllib.request.urlretrieve('http://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/efetch.fcgi?db=nuccore&id=' + mystring + '&rettype=fasta&retmode=text', 'C:/Users/User/Documents/mRNA.fasta')
```

It creates the file but is then empty, i have no clue what the problem is. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your resulting URL contains a space; you put it there yourself with:

```
mystring = ' '
```

If I replace that with an empty string instead your code appears to work:

```
mystring = ''
```

Rather than use string concatenation, you can use a list and use the [`str.join()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) to build your value:

```
elements = []
for element in root.findall('.//Link/Id'):
    elements.append(element.text)
mystring = ','.join(elements)
```

I used the [`Element.findall()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.findall) with an [XPath expression](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#elementtree-xpath) to list all matching Id nodes.

Comment: I can't bloody believe it... Thank you